mediapipe TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported: ERROR
I've been working on hand gesture controlled led brightness on Arduino. And i get this error in python code.
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.8

and this is the code that i wrote
import serial
import cvzone
import math
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
serialcomm = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
serialcomm.timeout = 1
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8, maxHands=1)
l=[]
while True:
    success,img =cap.read()
    img=cv2.resize(img,(500, 500))
    img=detector.findHands(img)
    l,box = detector.findPosition(img,draw=False)
    if l:
        #f=detector.fingersUp()
        x1=l[4][0]
        y1=l[4][1]
        x2=l[8][0]
        y2=l[8][1]
        cv2.circle(img,(x1,y1),7,(0,255,255),1)
        cv2.circle(img,(x2,y2),7,(0,255,255),1)
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)
        d=int(math.sqrt(math.pow(x2 - x1, 2)+math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) * 1.0))
        d=int((d/110)*255)
        e='\n'
        if 0<d<256:
            cv2.putText(img,str(d),(20,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,.7,(255,255,255),1)     
            serialcomm.write(str(d).encode())
            serialcomm.write(e.encode())
                     
    cv2.imshow('Image',img)  
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

and there is full error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 9
      7 serialcomm.timeout = 1
      8 cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
----> 9 detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8, maxHands=1)
     10 l=[]
     11 while True:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cvzone\HandTrackingModule.py:33, in HandDetector.__init__(self, mode, maxHands, detectionCon, minTrackCon)
     30 self.minTrackCon = minTrackCon
     32 self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
---> 33 self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
     34                                 self.detectionCon, self.minTrackCon)
     35 self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
     36 self.tipIds = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py:114, in Hands.__init__(self, static_image_mode, max_num_hands, model_complexity, min_detection_confidence, min_tracking_confidence)
     89 def __init__(self,
     90              static_image_mode=False,
     91              max_num_hands=2,
     92              model_complexity=1,
     93              min_detection_confidence=0.5,
     94              min_tracking_confidence=0.5):
     95   """Initializes a MediaPipe Hand object.
     96 
     97   Args:
   (...)
    112       https://solutions.mediapipe.dev/hands#min_tracking_confidence.
    113   """
--> 114   super().__init__(
    115       binary_graph_path=_BINARYPB_FILE_PATH,
    116       side_inputs={
    117           'model_complexity': model_complexity,
    118           'num_hands': max_num_hands,
    119           'use_prev_landmarks': not static_image_mode,
    120       },
    121       calculator_params={
    122           'palmdetectioncpu__TensorsToDetectionsCalculator.min_score_thresh':
    123               min_detection_confidence,
    124           'handlandmarkcpu__ThresholdingCalculator.threshold':
    125               min_tracking_confidence,
    126       },
    127       outputs=[
    128           'multi_hand_landmarks', 'multi_hand_world_landmarks',
    129           'multi_handedness'
    130       ])

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py:259, in SolutionBase.__init__(self, binary_graph_path, graph_config, calculator_params, graph_options, side_inputs, outputs, stream_type_hints)
    256 for stream_name in self._output_stream_type_info.keys():
    257   self._graph.observe_output_stream(stream_name, callback, True)
--> 259 self._input_side_packets = {
    260     name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
    261     for name, data in (side_inputs or {}).items()
    262 }
    263 self._graph.start_run(self._input_side_packets)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py:260, in <dictcomp>(.0)
    256 for stream_name in self._output_stream_type_info.keys():
    257   self._graph.observe_output_stream(stream_name, callback, True)
    259 self._input_side_packets = {
--> 260     name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
    261     for name, data in (side_inputs or {}).items()
    262 }
    263 self._graph.start_run(self._input_side_packets)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py:571, in SolutionBase._make_packet(self, packet_data_type, data)
    568   return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(
    569       data, image_format=image_frame.ImageFormat.SRGB)
    570 else:
--> 571   return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)

TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.8



what results did you find when you looked for existing questions and answers on this problem?

I couldn't find any answers to this problem because other existing questions were not asking for the same python code.
